# a noun clause at the end of a sentence

Tags: sentence-structure, nouns, clauses

I came upon a sentence which I can't understand.

> News soon get around that he had resigned.

As you can see, the noun clause (that he had resigned) is placed at the end of the sentence.

I guess the noun clause describes the noun "News".

I can't figure out why the noun and the noun clause are divided.

Is it possible?

Comment: That's *News soon **got** around...* Would it help you to note that your example sentence could start with a definite article? 1: ***The** news soon got around that he had resigned.* Which can then be trivially re-sequenced to 2: *The news **that he had resigned** soon got around.* Where arguably could be seen as just two consecutive noun phrases both referring to the same thing, similar to ***The gossip John** told everyone about it*. Does that help?

Comment: @FumbleFingers the sentence is from Oxford dictionary. there isn't a definite article. anyway thanks but I don't get it still.

Comment: [That-clause as a noun clause](https://www.englishgrammar.org/thatclause-noun-clause/#:~:text=A%20that%2Dclause%20is%20an,object%20of%20the%20verb%20believe.)

Comment: The only reason I suggested adding the initial definite article was because it's *slightly* more idiomatic to include it in both my alternatives. It's sightly *less* idiomatic to include it in the exact phrasing of *your* example, but that's beside the point. Note that it makes no difference to the meaning of *any* of them whether there's a definite article before ***news*** or not. My point was simply that we can consider both *[the] news* and *that he had resigned* as both being "noun phrases", and it's easier (for me) to see them as being ***in apposition*** if they occur consecutively....

Comment: ...and if you're happy to understand *John Smith, the town gossip, told everyone the news* as starting with ***two noun phrases in apposition***, I thought that would help you see how it's working with a "that- clause".

Comment: Note that my argument here turns on accepting that both *[the] news* and *that he had resigned* are two noun phrases that effectively both refer to the same thing. But although it's "syntactically valid" to use *either* of them in isolation as the subject of the sentence, it's not very idiomatic to use the "that- clause" on it's own like that here. So *That he had resigned soon got around* is very unlikely compared to *The news soon got around* (which latter obviously requires more context telling us ***what specific*** news travelled fast).

Answer (score 4):

This is an example of [Extraposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraposition): the basic sentence is

> News that he had resigned soon got around.

So "that he had resigned" is a complement of "news".

Answer (score 2):

When the subject part of the sentence gets longer, the subject can be divided. You can refer to the 'end-weight principle'.